# How to find the max occurrence (highest count) of a value in an Array of Objects in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, loops

I have the data in the following format:

```
 [
        {
            "product": "Term Insurance",
            "ViewTime": "Wed Jan 20 14:13:05 IST 2021",
            "userBought": true,
            "userLocation": {
                "loaded": true,
                "userAllowed": true,
                "coordinates": {
                    "lng": 70.8856,
                    "lat": 19.0748
                }
            },
            "category": "Health Insurance"
        },
        {
            "product": "Car Insurance",
            "ViewTime": "Wed Jan 20 15:40:31 IST 2021",
            "userBought": true,
            "userLocation": {
                "loaded": true,
                "userAllowed": true,
                "coordinates": {
                    "lng": 70.8856,
                    "lat": 19.0748
                }
            },
            "category": "Motor Insurance"
        },
        {
            "product": "Car Insurance",
            "ViewTime": "Wed Jan 20 15:42:52 IST 2021",
            "userBought": true,
            "userLocation": {
                "loaded": true,
                "userAllowed": true,
                "coordinates": {
                    "lng": 70.8856,
                    "lat": 19.0748
                }
            },
            "category": "Motor Insurance"
        }]
```

I want to map through the array and calculate the maxCategory and maxProduct from the number of occurrences using Javascript. Like here the maxCategory would be "Motor Insurance" and maxProduct would be "Car Insurance". Is there any clean, efficient way to do it?

Comment: have you tried something? what does not work? please add your code.

Comment: Please show what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the properties and then apply reduce method, try this:

```js
let cars = [
        {
            "product": "Term Insurance",
            "ViewTime": "Wed Jan 20 14:13:05 IST 2021",
            "userBought": true,
            "userLocation": {
                "loaded": true,
                "userAllowed": true,
                "coordinates": {
                    "lng": 70.8856,
                    "lat": 19.0748
                }
            },
            "category": "Health Insurance"
        },
        {
            "product": "Car Insurance",
            "ViewTime": "Wed Jan 20 15:40:31 IST 2021",
            "userBought": true,
            "userLocation": {
                "loaded": true,
                "userAllowed": true,
                "coordinates": {
                    "lng": 70.8856,
                    "lat": 19.0748
                }
            },
            "category": "Motor Insurance"
        },
        {
            "product": "Car Insurance",
            "ViewTime": "Wed Jan 20 15:42:52 IST 2021",
            "userBought": true,
            "userLocation": {
                "loaded": true,
                "userAllowed": true,
                "coordinates": {
                    "lng": 70.8856,
                    "lat": 19.0748
                }
            },
            "category": "Motor Insurance"
        }]

let counterCategories = {}
for (property of cars){
counterCategories[property.category] = 1 + (counterCategories[property.category] || 0)
}
console.log(counterCategories)


let entries = Object.entries(counterCategories);
let result = entries.reduce((acc, el) => acc[1] < el[1] ? el[0] : acc[0])
console.log('maxCategory: ' + result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for an efficient way to do this. I've used a single loop to find out the result. You can check this.

```js
const data = [
    {
        product: 'Term Insurance',
        ViewTime: 'Wed Jan 20 14:13:05 IST 2021',
        userBought: true,
        userLocation: {
            loaded: true,
            userAllowed: true,
            coordinates: {
                lng: 70.8856,
                lat: 19.0748,
            },
        },
        category: 'Health Insurance',
    },
    {
        product: 'Car Insurance',
        ViewTime: 'Wed Jan 20 15:40:31 IST 2021',
        userBought: true,
        userLocation: {
            loaded: true,
            userAllowed: true,
            coordinates: {
                lng: 70.8856,
                lat: 19.0748,
            },
        },
        category: 'Motor Insurance',
    },
    {
        product: 'Car Insurance',
        ViewTime: 'Wed Jan 20 15:42:52 IST 2021',
        userBought: true,
        userLocation: {
            loaded: true,
            userAllowed: true,
            coordinates: {
                lng: 70.8856,
                lat: 19.0748,
            },
        },
        category: 'Motor Insurance',
    },
];

let [maxProductCount, maxCategoryCount, maxProduct, maxCategory, tmpObj] = [0, 0, null, null, {}];

data.forEach(({ product, category }) => {
    tmpObj[product] = (tmpObj[product] || 0) + 1;
    tmpObj[category] = (tmpObj[category] || 0) + 1;
    if (tmpObj[product] > maxProductCount) {
        maxProductCount = tmpObj[product];
        maxProduct = product;
    }
    if (tmpObj[category] > maxCategoryCount) {
        maxCategoryCount = tmpObj[category];
        maxCategory = category;
    }
});

console.log({ maxProduct, maxCategory });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#countBy) `countBy` method:

```js
let data = [...]
_.countBy(data, (item) => item.category);
// {"Health Insurance": 1, "Motor Insurance": 2}
_.countBy(data, (item) => item.product);
// {"Term Insurance": 1, "Car Insurance": 2}
```